# Detecting the MIME type with a php upload script is not working

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to detect the mime type of a audio file that is uploaded via php. I am allowing .mp3 .mp4 and .wav. For some reason it still says that it is an incorrect file type even if it is one of those types. Here is my validation code:

```
$allowedExts = array("wav", "mp3", "mp4", "mpeg");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wave") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp4")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg"))&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

  }
```

If somebody figures this out then please submit that fixed part of the code and not just a portion of it please. I appreciate any help!

Comment: try to echo $_FILES["file"]["type"] what it gives & size

Comment: it says audio/wav and i changed the validation from audio/wave to audio/wav ..... still not working though

Comment: and $extension is wav not .wav would that cause a problem???

Comment: no since you are validating without dot 
what is the size ?

Comment: the size is 321312 so i just need to allow that to be bigger right??

Comment: obviously :) 
Do it and let's see

Comment: Just got this to work... i changed the audio/wave to audio/wav the max size to 1048576 (1gb) and audio/mpeg to audio/mp3 thank you all for your service

Comment: good it worked but 
1 GB might cause other problems :)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to check the mime type would be to let phps internal functions process the file. The content of $_FILES["file"] can be partially easily faked by an attacker. Additionaly, you have a reliable source, how your mime type is spelled.

Try [finfo](http://php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-open.php)
http://php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-open.php

```
$allowedMimeTypes = array('audio/wave', 'audio/mp4', 'audio/whatevermore');
$allowedExts = array('wav', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg');
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime = $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);  

if(in_array($mime, $allowedMimeTypes) && filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) < 200000 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    echo 'yeah';
}
```